# System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, postback, xss

> Server Error in '/WebSite10'
>   Application. Invalid postback or
>   callback argument.  Event validation
>   is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

I get that mistake.

Note that: I do generate some controls dynamically and call their events..Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to regenerate those controls dynamically on each page_load. Even on Postback. You also need to set their Id to the same value each time.

Comment: oooh.. So there is inconsistency between what is postback. I think the controlsIDs are all named. I will see what controls i dont regenerate..